# create string that represent as slice

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

it is possible to use string for slice the list?

i have example like this

```py
m = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(m[:-1])
print(m[1:-1:])
print(m[::2])
```

above code will result

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 5]
```

so i want use string to do something like that

```py
m = [1,2,3,4,5]
inp = input('slice the list ')

#and user will input [:-1], [1:-1:], or [::2]

#slice the list using that input
#m[inp]??
```

if this possible, how to make this approach?

i cannot find answer for this anywhere or i just don't know what keyword should i type for search this

Comment: Outside of a few very specific situations, user input shouldn't be code, or have any connection to the language you're writing your program in. There are a few reasons: it's awkward UI design, it introduces massive security problems, and it makes reimplementing things in a different language much more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: An answer provided suggests using *eval()*. That will work under controlled situations but is generally considered bad form. You could write a fairly trivial parser and then construct a *slice* class. But, as @user2357112 rightly implies - this is rather bizarre and potentially unmanageable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a `slice` object and use that as an arg to the `[]` operator (or equivalent `__getitem__` magic method).  `slice` takes optional `int` arguments (or `None` to use the defaults) that correspond to the numbers in the `-1:1:` syntax.

So if you want to parse a string like `[1:-1:]` without directly using `eval` (which can be dangerous since it will also parse all sorts of *other* expressions), you can do something along the lines of:

- strip the `[]` characters
- split on `:`
- pass the `:`-separated numbers as args to `slice()`, using `None` for missing numbers.

E.g.:

```
>>> inp = "[1:-1:]"
>>> inp_slice = slice(*(int(i) if i else None for i in inp.strip("[]").split(":")))
>>> [1,2,3,4,5][inp_slice]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Once you understand how the `slice` object works, you're of course free to accept the input from the user in other forms (e.g. there's no reason to require them to input the `[]` part if you know that the input is always going to be used to slice a list).